# Remove index, name, d_type and ' ' while printing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I print out just the number, without space and ' ' ? Only: 5.125

Here is input:

```
df['Letter']=df['str'].str.len()+df['str2'].str.len()
df['num']=df['num']/df['Letter']

df.nsmallest(2, ['num']).iloc[[1]][['num']].to_string(index=False,header=False)
```

Here is output:

```
' 5.125'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `trim()`.
https://www.journaldev.com/23625/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip

It will remove useless spaces like in front of your string and at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want it as a string then you'll need to access via index or list location, here I've just returned a list and got the last element. then you can print it as an integer value as opposed to a string.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'num' : np.random.randint(0,50,size=10)})

print(df)

   num
0   44
1   47
2    0
3    3
4    3
5   39
6    9
7   19
8   21
9   36
```

---

```
print(df.nsmallest(2,['num'])['num'].tolist()[-1])
out:
3
```

---

```
df.nsmallest(2, ['num']).iloc[[1]][['num']].to_string(index=False,header=False)
out:
' 3'
```